# Screen splits into two after Debian 9 installation

Tags: debian, xorg, intel-graphics

I have installed Debian 9 (Stretch) in my HP Desktop (Pro One 600 G2 having Intel HD Graphics). Installation seemed to have proceeded without any hiccup, but after installation when the computer re-booted, I have my screen split into two horizontally.

All the screen resolutions are listed but the screen still is split (see below). I am at a loss what to do. Infant in all other Linux distribution, the problem is same!

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: Do you have this at the login screen as well or only after logon ?

Answer (score 1):

I Have the same problem.

I Tested Ubuntu 16.04 & 17.04 distros (ElementaryOS Freya, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Bodhi) with the same efect.

I upgraded the BIOS to the last version 02.18 (June-2017) but no change.

The **solution** is to activate the UEFI boot and deactivate the Legacy mode. As commented in https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97822#c83

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know if the intel gpu module is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep intel
```

I think it should say something like `intel_agp`

Next you would need the native resolutions of your monitors/screens.

Update: Apparently, hp.com says it is 1920x1080, I guess vsync is 60hz, but I cannot reliably tell.

You could also try to issue `X -configure` as `root`, this will create an xorg.conf for you.

If this fails, then you need to create an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20intel.conf` file with the correct settings. Note that intel drivers usually need the kernel modesetting, if you use `nomodeset` or `vga=` kernel parameters, you will have to remove these.

For starters, check if you have an `[someNumber][some_name].conf` file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, if you do not, create a files there named 20intel.conf with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

If you have, what does it contain ?

Then, do Ctrl+Alt+F1, login on the terminal and restart your display manager:

```
sudo service restart gdm
```

There are many resources online for creating xorg.conf files.

e.g: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/xorg-conf-for-intel-hd-graphics-4175455283/